# Почему не срабатывает условие?

Tags: php

Почему не срабатывает условие? Понимаю, что ошибка в первом кейсе, но не знаю как сделать диапазон с 1 по 5(включительно)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Даже если php позволяет выражения в `case`, результатом этих выражений будет булевское значение, не совпадающее с `$day`. Напишите `if`/`else if` и не выделывайтесь :).

Ну и при каких значениях `$day` вот это будет истинно `($day == 1 && $day <= 5)`?

A вот это `($day == 6 && $day == 7)`?

Ну а здесь-то Вы точно хотели написать "или" `($day <= 0 6 && $day > 7)`.

```
switch($day) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
    echo ("This is a weekday.");
    break;
  case 6:
  case 7:
    echo ("This is a weekend day.");
    break;
  default:
    echo ("This is an unknown day.");
}
```

Comment: да я знаю) Просто задание такое)

Answer (score 0):

У Вас противоречивые условия. Не может быть день меньше нуля И больше семи (одновременно). И т.д.

```
switch($day){
  case($day>=1 && $day<=5):...
...
}
```